# How to change the magnet uri handler in Google Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, bittorrent, deluge, magnet-links

I removed the Transmission BitTorrent client from my Ubuntu and installed Deluge. Now magnet URIs don't work anymore. How to tell Chrome to launch the new app instead?

Comment: I have found an entry in gconf-editor under /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet but I changed it and it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command "/usr/bin/deluge '%s'"
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/needs_terminal false
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled true
```

Change `/usr/bin/deluge` to the correct location for your system.