# Change default application of a URI scheme in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, pidgin, yahoo-messenger, uri

I accidentally make Pidgin the default app for Yahoo Messenger URI scheme (ymsgr://) in Google Chrome. Now, whenever I click on a Yahoo Messenger URI scheme, instead of appearing a popup chat box, nothing happens. How can I change the default app to associate with this URI scheme back to Yahoo Messenger?

I found a similar problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/331309/how-to-change-the-magnet-uri-handler-in-google-chrome). But I am using Windows 7, not Ubuntu, so the solution cannot be applied in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations`

or Start> Default Programs> Associate a file type or protocol with a program

Answer (score 0):

The file associations in `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations` doesn't cover all possible file extensions and actions that can be taken by default on those extensions, such as editing and printing.

This application: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html, can help you edit defaults that don't appear in the control panel list.